# Resque job not actually backgrounding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, resque

It is instead taking up my processor, and then effectually timing out.

I have in my controller :

```
after_save :handle_file

def handle_test
  Resque.enqueue UnpackFileOnS3, parent.id
end
```

It hits this mark, and then the entire app waits for it to set up and upload the files as prescribed inside my Job. Then it predictably times out because it takes awhile to upload it.

This occurs in my console as well.. If I run :

```
Resque.enqueue UnpackFileOnS3, 4
```

Then instead of enqueue'ing it, it locks up my console as it tries to run the entire file. I *think* that normally, console would just enqueue it to a worker and redis..

Why isn't this actually happening in the background? As I assume if that were the case, the timeouts would not occur.

Comment: Just checking: Did you start a Resque worker in the background?

Comment: With `rake resque:work QUEUE=*`. And it would have to technically be working since it does run the process but at the expense of having the entire server wait for it to finish.

Comment: But come to think of it, none of the queues when I run `resque.info` in my console show any response, though my loggers from the resque worker itself are properly outputting.. Its as if Resque is being completely ignored, and its running my Class as a Server process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are running resque in an inline mode. In this mode queing is disabled. Check your configs for this kind of code:

```
Resque.inline = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "cucumber"
#or whatever, important part is the inline option
```

Comment: Ah you are genius. Thanks so much Gurudev Tumas.